# validar que una fila no se repita en la tabla, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy buscando la forma de validar que una fila no se repita en mi tabla...Tengo un select que me va agregando un producto y mediante un boton lo agrega como fila en la tabla, pero necesito validar que no se pueda volver a ingresar ese mismo producto nuevamente

Tengo esta funcion jquery con la funcionalidad que les comento, pero la funcion que tendria que hacer la validacion no funciona (no da ningun error, simplemente no funciona):

```
function agregar(){
        //e.preventDefault();
         material_id = $('#amaterial_id').val();
         material = $("#amaterial_id option:selected").text();
         cantidad = $('#cantidad').val();
         seriado = $("#amaterial_id option:selected").data('seriado');
         $('#seriados').val(seriado);

         if (checkId(material_id)) {
                return alert('El ID ya está siendo usado');
        }
            if (material_id!="" && cantidad!="" && cantidad>0 ){


                if (seriado == 0) {
                    var fila = '<tr class="selected" id="fila'+cont+'"><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="eliminar('+cont+');">X</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="cargarSeries('+cont+');">Cargar Series</button></td><td><input type="hidden" name="material_id[]" value="'+material_id+'">'+material+'</td><td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"></td></tr>';
                } else {
                var fila = '<tr class="selected" id="fila'+cont+'"><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="eliminar('+cont+');">X</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" disabled="disabled" ">No Seriable</button></td><td><input type="hidden" name="material_id[]" value="'+material_id+'">'+material+'</td><td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"></td></tr>';
                }
                // var fila = '<tr class="selected" id="fila'+cont+'"><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onclick="eliminar('+cont+');">X</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onclick="seriado('+cont+');">Seriado</button></td><td><input type="hidden" name="material_id[]" value="'+material_id+'">'+material+'</td><td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"></td><td>input type="text" name="seriados" value="'+seriado+'"<td/></tr>';
                //console.log(seriado);
                cont++;
                //total++;
                $('#guardar').show();
                limpiarControles();
                //evaluar();
                $('#detalles').append(fila);
            }else{
                alert("Revise que se hallan seleccionado productos");
                $('#guardar').hide();
            }

            function checkId (material_id) {
    let ids = document.querySelectorAll('#detalles td[for="material_id"]');

  return [].filter.call(ids, td => td.textContent === material_id).length === 1;

    }
    }
```

Alguna idea adicional para hacer esta validacion?

Saludos a todos

Comment: Confirmaste que tu _textContent_ dentro del filter apunta hacia el id de tu fila?

Comment: Hoal, si, se supone que el id va cambiando por el contador (seria fila1, fila2)

Answer (score 0):

con este if logre que funcione pero solo lo hace una vez, despues de agregar un producto diferente ya no funciona:

```
if(material_id == $('#test').val()){
                    alert('repetido');
                }else{
                    if (seriado == 0) {
                    var fila = '<tr class="selected" id="fila'+cont+'"><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="eliminar('+cont+');">X</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="cargarSeries('+cont+');">Cargar Series</button></td><td><input type="hidden" id="test" name="material_id[]" value="'+material_id+'">'+material+'</td><td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"></td></tr>';
                } else {
                var fila = '<tr class="selected"  id="fila'+cont+'"><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="eliminar('+cont+');">X</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" disabled="disabled" ">No Seriable</button></td><td><input type="hidden" name="material_id[]" value="'+material_id+'">'+material+'</td><td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"></td></tr>';
                }
                    $('#detalles').append(fila);
                }
```